# Nova notifications

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova, laravel-notification

I create notifications

```
     $notification = Laravel\Nova\Notifications\NovaNotification::make()
                ->message($softsMessage)
                ->type('info');
```

But I want to create 2 lines in one notification. How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

To create a notification with multiple lines in Laravel Nova, you can make use of  line breaks to format the message.

```php
$notification = Laravel\Nova\Notifications\NovaNotification::make()
    ->message("First line of the notification\nSecond line of the notification")
    ->type('info');
```